# Three.js - Scene does not load

Tags: three.js

I am trying to render a basic three.js scene.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Example 01.02 - First Scene</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/three.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
<div id="WebGL-output">
</div>

<!-- Javascript code that runs our Three.js examples -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    // once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
    function init() {

        // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as objects, cameras and lights.
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // create a render and set the size
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColorHex();
        renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE));
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        // show axes in the screen
        var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(20);
        scene.add(axes);

        // create the ground plane
        var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60, 20);
        var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xcccccc});
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);

        // rotate and position the plane
        plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
        plane.position.x = 15;
        plane.position.y = 0;
        plane.position.z = 0;

        // add the plane to the scene
        scene.add(plane);

        // create a cube
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 4, 4);
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true});
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

        // position the cube
        cube.position.x = -4;
        cube.position.y = 3;
        cube.position.z = 0;

        // add the cube to the scene
        scene.add(cube);

        // create a sphere
        var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(4, 20, 20);
        var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x7777ff, wireframe: true});
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);

        // position the sphere
        sphere.position.x = 20;
        sphere.position.y = 4;
        sphere.position.z = 2;

        // add the sphere to the scene
        scene.add(sphere);

        // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
        camera.position.x = -30;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 30;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // add the output of the renderer to the html element
        document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // render the scene
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    window.onload = init;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is an HTML file that i drag and drop onto a browser.
In the same directory with that file, i have a folder called `libs` and inside i have the `three.js` and `three.mini.js` libraries.

I downloaded the three.js zip file from its website and inside there were tons of files.
But since these libaries were the ones that the code required, i just put these two javascript files, and ommitted all the other fiels contained in the zip file.

When i drag and drop the `html` file onto a browser, the only thing i see is a blank white image.

EDIT: JS console errors:

```
*Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
*Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined at init (test.html:29)
```

Comment: first of all you have to continously call `renderer.render(scene, camera);` for example on `requestAnimationFrame` callback.

Comment: do you get any javascript errors on browser console? If so update your question

Comment: You are right. I did get errors. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run things locally as descripted [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally) ?

Personally I use the python version :

> If you have Python installed, it should be enough to run this from a command line (from your working directory):
>   //Python 2.x
>   python -m SimpleHTTPServer
>   //Python 3.x
>   python -m http.server
>   This will serve files from the current directory at localhost under port 8000, i.e in the address bar type: http://localhost:8000/

Then you can access your file browsing into your localhost (it is now necessary to do so because of resource access policies changing on web browsers).

**EDIT**

After testing your code, I actually just removed the `renderer.setClearColorHex();` line 36, and just placed it in a folder with three.min.js, and it worked fine when I opened it from my folder.

Comment: I removed that line and i got that on the console:

Comment: test.html:7 GET file:///C:/Graphics/libs/three.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
test.html:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    at init (test.html:29)

Comment: Oh, i saw your link and i visited. I gotta have a server to run files. I got npm's http-server, but where do i place the file now?

Comment: I think you actually just need to add three.min.js in the same repo as your html file (you can find it here : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/build/three.min.js).

Comment: Your error does not come from the local server stuff actually, it is just your version of three which is useless. You just need to :  
1. create a repository for your file  
2. add the html file in it  
3. add three.min.js from the link above in it  
4. import three.min.js in your html file (<script type="text/javascript" src="three.min.js"></script>)  
5. open your html file clicking on it.
Then it should work !